# How to make the tables logically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-express

Database Diagram

I'm trying to create master Info table that has all his fields additionally to other 3 tables. so, the master info table has many phone number, many encoder numbers and many control room numbers. therefore, I have made them in this way but I'm not sure that what if i need to do the opposite, like put the statin_No in each table? instead of putting each table primary key in the masterInfoTable like, putting Audio_keyNo in MasterInfoTable?

the masterInfo table contains(
Station_No, Encoder_make, Encoder_Model, Audio_keyNo, ControlRoom_keyNo, and Encoder_KeyNo)
the AudioTable has(
Audio_KeyNO, Audio_No)
The ControlRoom table and Encoder table have the keyno and control room or encoder no.
any thing end with KeyNO is a primary Key.

Comment: So what's the key in masterinfo?

Comment: The problem I cant past a pic of my work here because im new to here and I dont have enough reputations. so, I made four tables. first called StationTable and it has Station_No( primary key), Encoder_make, Encoder_Model, Audio_keyNo(fk), ControlRoom_keyNo(fk), and Encoder_KeyNo(fk). the second table is AudioTable has( Audio_KeyNO, Audio_No) The ControlRoom table has(ControlRoom_keyNo(pk) and ControlRoom_no) and the EncoderTable has (Encoder_KeyNo(pk) and Encoder_no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create you main station table and other three tables for Encoder, Phone, Control Room. Connect these three tables to the main table you have. So, the main table will have a primary key and three foreign keys for the three tables. This is the best what can i think of from your problem's description. Let me know if you any further question.

Comment: Thank you. I do appreciate your help.